# Get Stripe Payout from Balance Transaction

Tags: c#, .net, stripe-payments

I'm using the .NET Stripe Api to create a report that shows all balance transactions that have occured within the date range for a specific connected account.

One feature that we'd like to implement in this report is to show payout data for each transaction, so that our clients can see for each transaction when that revenue is expected to be deposited in their bank account.

As far as I can tell, the Stripe Api doesn't have a way to connect a balance transaction to a payout. It is possible to get all balance transactions for a single payout, but it isn't able to do the reverse.

Is there a way to get the payout that a balance transaction is tied to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a direct link between Payouts given a BalanceTransaction (but as you said, the link exists the other way around).

There are long workarounds to how you can kind of get what you want but are far from ideal.

Longer answer would be:

You have a BalanceTransaction which has `available_on` for when that Balance moved into your available balance.

You can list Payouts that were created after that `available_on` date using the `arrival_date[gte]` param when listing Payouts.

With those Payouts, list all BalanceTransactions on that Payout to confirm if that BT was part of that Payout.